# filtered recycler view not getting correct card position on swipe

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-filterable

So, I have a RecyclerView that uses "swipe to dismiss" and implements filterable.

What works:  The swipe to dismiss and filterable work individually as expected.  I can swipe to dismiss with the proper animation (I also delete a row from my SQLite db upon this action).  I can also filter the cards using the native filterable.

What doesn't work:  When I swipe to dismiss after filtering, the position is incorrect and as expected then, the corresponding incorrect row is deleted from my db.

What I think:  I believe I need to somehow update my Activity arrayList after/during the filter process.

my search code in Activity

```
//create options menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_jar_options, menu);
    /*return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);*/

    action_search = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_jar_action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) action_search.getActionView();
    searchView.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
    search(searchView);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//search
private void search(SearchView searchView) {
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toLowerCase());
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

my swipe code in Activity (cleaned up for clarity purposes)

```
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction){
            if (direction ==ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT){
                //swipe right - delete card
                final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                //get necessary data from item
                s_deleteIdentifier = arrayList.get(position).getIdentifier();
                s_deleteIdentifier = (!FormatHelper.isStringEmpty(s_deleteIdentifier)) ? s_deleteIdentifier : "";
                s_deleteName = arrayList.get(position).getName();
                s_deleteName = (!FormatHelper.isStringEmpty(s_deleteName)) ? s_deleteName : "";

                //REMOVE ME after testing
                Toast.makeText(JarActivity.this, "" +position +" " +s_deleteName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                arrayList.remove(position);

                //user confirms delete, so delete row from db
                DatabaseHelper.getInstance(JarActivity.this).deleteRow(
                                    "table",
                                    "IDENTIFIER = ?",
                                    new String[] {s_deleteIdentifier}
                );
        }
```

my filter code in adapter

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter(){
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence){
            String charString;

            if (charSequence != null) charString = charSequence.toString();
            else charString = "";

            if (charString.isEmpty()){
                arrayListFiltered = arrayList;
            }else{
                ArrayList<JarObject> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (JarObject jarObject : arrayList) {
                    if (jarObject.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            jarObject.getLocation().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            jarObject.getUserNote().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ||
                            jarObject.getSummary().toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                            )
                        filteredList.add(jarObject);
                }
                arrayListFiltered = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = arrayListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            arrayListFiltered = (ArrayList<JarObject>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in your original list and the filtered list won't be in the same positions. I don't have the ability to throw together an example right now but you should be able to override the adapters `getItemId()` method to return something meaningful and use the `ViewHolder.getItemId()` to get the actual item you want to delete instead of depending on the position.

You could also expose your filtered list so you can access it from your activity to get the item from the filtered list based off the position, then search your original list to get the proper position.

Comment: I'm trying to use the `getItemId()` and it returns -1 every time.  Not sure what that is telling me.  I'm searching for answers to that now.

Comment: are you overriding the `getItemId()` in your adapter?

Comment: Yes, I belive so. `@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }`   in adapter

Comment: I think you also need to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#hasStableIds()

Comment: whew.  my code did not like that :).  It crashed at run time as soon as I swiped a card.  Perhaps the rest of my code is all tweaked for using getAdapterPosition().  Not Sure.

Comment: You could just go with the second option I outlined. Where you use the item from the filtered list to find its original position. Or use an `Id` on the item for your delete instead of the position.

Comment: I will try that next.  May take me a bit of time to pull that together.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I used the second suggestion.  Added a method in my adapter that sent back an identifier of the actual card.  This method is then called from my onSwipe in the Activity.